# Represent 10000 booleans using only 10000 bits

Tags: algorithm, bit

I want to represent 10000 bits of information.(Each can be either one or zero). Is there any way I can do this?

Wikipedia explains [a bit hack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_manipulation#Bit_manipulation_in_the_C_programming_language) to achieve this. But then it asks me to have a number that's as large as 2^10000 for storing 10000 bits.

Is there some way that's tractable even for storing large number of bits?

Comment: You can't ask for implementation details *and* specify "language-agnostic"..

Comment: An integer on a 32-bit machine, used as a bit-field, can hold 32 bits.  So an array of 32 integers can hold 1024 bits...

Comment: @harold I am basically asking for an algorithm. And that algorithm should not use any language specific constructs.

Comment: Or, if you look at bytes (think array, list, ...) you need 1250 Bytes to store 10000 bits

Comment: @antlersoft an array of 32 integers itself uses 32*4*8 bits.

Comment: Sounds like you just want normal BigInteger

Comment: possible duplicate of [C hack for storing a bit that takes 1 bit space?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483986/c-hack-for-storing-a-bit-that-takes-1-bit-space)

Comment: This isn't really a language-agnostic question. In some languages, you can simply declare a packed array of Booleans. In others, you have to do your own bit-twiddling. As for not using any "language specific constructs", that's not really possible; bitwise operations on integers are the only sensible approach in some languages, but they're language-specific in that not all languages provide them.

Comment: a bit vector is a good choice for this

Comment: It's a fairly trivial algorithm once you specify a language. In C: use an array of char's, i/8 for index, 1 << (i%8) for mask. OR with the mask to set a bit, AND with ~(mask) to clear a bit, AND with the mask to check a bit. Replace 8 with the # of bits in a char for exotic architectures.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: Use `unsigned char`, not `char`, and use `CHAR_BIT`, not `8`. Of course that's hardly language-agnostic.

Comment: I have now removed the tag language agnostic.

Comment: Removing language-agnostic doesn't really help if you don't specify a language.

Comment: @Keith: Since only left shifts are employed, there's no difference between signed and unsigned.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: 1. Who says only left shifts are employed? 2. Even with left shifts, certain shifts are well defined for an unsigned left operand, and undefined for a signed left operand. 3. Just use `unsigned char` explicitly, and you don't have to *care* how shifts are defined for signed arguments.

Comment: 1. I just did :) 2. Cite please.

Comment: @SevaAlekseyev: 1. You want to be able both to store and to extract specified bits; doesn't that require both left and right shifts? 2. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.5.7p4. `1<<7` is representable in an 8-bit unsigned type, but not in an 8-bit signed type. Bitwise operations on signed integers: Just say no.

Comment: No it does not. See my first comment. You just need the left shift to form the mask. Also, how often do you meet real life implementations of C where (signed char)1<<7 is not the same as (signed char)0x80?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As wikipedia explains, a bit field is an appropriate choice here.  a bit field that can hold 10,000 bits has 2^10000 states.

A good choice for doing this (given that integers are 32/64 bits) is a bit vector, which is asked about and explained in excruciating detail here:

[bit vector implementation of set in Programming Pearls, 2nd Edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11400242/bit-vector-implementation-of-set-in-programming-pearls-2nd-edition/)

The general idea is that you use an array of integers which are used as bit fields.

Comment: Precisely. A common choice is to use a character array as a bit field, but this depends on your programming environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can make **bool** take 1 bit for example if you have a bunch of them eg. in a struct, like this:

struct A
{
  bool a:1, b:1, c:1, d:1, e:1;
};

Above method won't be useful if the number of variables are large. So instead create an array of integers of size 10000/4*8. It will create exactly 10000 bits. Now you can access each bit by using offset  and << or >>(like for accessing 55th bit, use floor(55/4*8) and >>55%32. you can reach that bit).

Comment: Yes, but then indexing is difficult.

Comment: You're assuming that an "integer" is exactly 32 bits. That's not even true for all implementations of C.

Comment: @Keith or you can use 'char' for simpler implementation

Comment: Ok, how many bits in a `char`? And is `char` signed or unsigned? Both answers vary even across conforming C implementations. Trying to make it "language agnostic" is even more difficult.

Comment: doesn't matter when you are using bit wise. Char always uses 8 bit.

Comment: Incorrect. In C, `char` is *at least* 8 bits; it can be bigger (compilers for some DSPs make `char` 16 or 32 bits). `CHAR_BIT` tells you how many bits in a `char` (or, equivalently, in a byte). And plain `char` may be either signed or unsigned; you want to use `unsigned char` for bitwise operations. In Java, `char` is 16 bits by definition. In Java, if I recall correctly, `char` is defined to be exactly 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ you can do this very simply, using one of two standard library containers:

### `std::vector<bool>`

This specialization of a standard vector acts (almost) like any other vector, but compresses its contents to one bit per element. Aside from enjoying that fact, you can just treat it like a vector:

```
// Create a vector of 10000 booleans
std::vector<bool> lots_of_bits(10000);
// Set all the odd ones to true
for (int i = 1; i < lots_of_bits.size(); i += 2) {
  lots_of_bits[i] = true;
}
// Add another 100 trues at the end
for (int j = 0; j < 100; ++j) {
  lots_of_bits.push_back(true);
}
// etc.
```

### `std::bitset<N>`

The "new, improved" bit vector which does not pretend to be a standard container. In particular, it's of fixed size and you need to know the size at compile time. That can be a bit restrictive, but it's otherwise a pretty useful class. Like `std::vector<bool>`, it implements the `[]` operator for getting and setting individual bits. It also supports the bitwise logical operators `&`, `|`, '^' and `~` (and, or, xor and not), as well as left and right bitshifts, and some other utilities.

Answer (score 0):

Is your concern that accessing bit number `n` requires shifting `n` times? If so, you can make the problem tractable by dividing your 10,000 bits into 10,000 / 8 buckets using an array of characters (assuming C or C++ here). Now you can access bit number `n` by figuring out what bucket that bit is in (`n / 8`) and then what position within the bucket (`n % 8`). Then you just do the masking. No extra storage required (except the padding at the end, so a few extra bits if you don't have a perfect multiple of 32 bits).

Comment: Use `CHAR_BIT` rather than `8` if you want complete portability -- and use `unsigned char` rather than plain `char`, which may be either signed or unsigned.